# Поставить 2 изображения на одном уровне

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы в item-images были 2 изображения на одном уровне, т.е. одно на другом.
Поставил position: absolute, они встали как надо, но вылезают за пределы item-images и перекрывают другие блоки.
Как это исправить?
HTML:

```
<div class="catalog">
        <div class="catalog-item">
            <div class="item-images">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">123</button>
        </div>
        <div class="catalog-item">
            <div class="item-images">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">123</button>
        </div>
        <div class="catalog-item">
            <div class="item-images">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">123</button>
        </div>
        <div class="catalog-item">
            <div class="item-images">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">123</button>
        </div>
        <div class="catalog-item">
            <div class="item-images">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">123</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0F054B;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #CD610A;
    color: #CD610A;
    font-family: Lobster;
    transition: .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #CD610A;
    border-color: #0F054B;
    color: #0F054B;
 }

.catalog {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.catalog-item {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    background-color: #CD610A;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.item-info {
    padding: 1em;
}

.catalog-item .btn {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.item-images {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
}

.item-images img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: А зачем одно изображение на другое накладываете? а вообще, задайте им размеры, не будут вылазить ) или overflow: hidden на родителя

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta Оверфлов обрезает, а задать размеры в процентах не влияет, в пикселях - неэффективно, т.к. плохо будет адаптация под экран работать, да и вообще будет выглядеть как костыль

Comment: не очень понятно чем в процентах то не устраивает?

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, оно становиться очень маленьким, даже на 100%

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, и всё равно, видно, что вылезает. Родительский блок маленький, а картинка чуть больше

Comment: из-за паддинга родительского блока, надо полагать

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, Нет, да и какая разница, если это не решает проблему

Comment: Проблему я описал, про размеры я сказал, что это неправильно, мне не нужно делать маленькие изображения, а также не нужно ставить волшебные числа в пикселях, тем более, потом добавлять адаптацию специально для того